# Why my css transition doesn't work

Tags: css

My css transition isn't working, I want to give my drop menu a transition and mine just doesn't respond. I hoped that you could help me fix it. I would also thank an explanation for my errors.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vero albucius singulis mea ut. Qui tibique mentitum ea, pro dicta euripidis te. Ut mel sale antiopam. Est nobis homero cu, pro in cetero fabellas.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vero albucius singulis mea ut. Qui tibique mentitum ea, pro dicta euripidis te. Ut mel sale antiopam. Est nobis homero cu, pro in cetero fabellas.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vero albucius singulis mea ut. Qui tibique mentitum ea, pro dicta euripidis te. Ut mel sale antiopam. Est nobis homero cu, pro in cetero fabellas

```css
body, html{
 margin:0;
 font:1em "papyrus";
 background-color: #f4d56e;
}

.content{
 padding: 30px;
}

.nav-main{
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #700707;
 height: 70px;
 color: white;
}

.nav-main .logo{
 float: left;
 height: 70px;
 padding: 15px 30px;
 line-height: 40px;
}

.nav-main img{
 margin-top: -30px;
 margin-right: -25px;
}

.nav-main > ul{
 margin:0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-main >ul > li{
 float: left;
}

.nav-item{
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 15px 126.1px;
 height: 40px;
 line-height: 45px;
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-item:hover{
 background-color: #B82023;
}
.drop-down-menu{
 display: none;
 height: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 top: 255;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #700707;
 list-style-type: none;
 overflow: hidden;

 -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
} /* this is the transition that is not working*/

.drop-down-menu li{
 padding: 0;
}

.drop-down-menu li:hover {
 background-color: #B82023;
 text-decoration:underline;
}

.drop-down-menu ul{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
}

.drop-down-menu li a {
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #700707;
 width: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 padding-top:  8px;
 padding-bottom: 8px;
 padding-left: 16px;
 padding-right: 7px;
 line-height: 50px;
}

.drop-down-menu a:hover {
 background-color: #B82023;
}


li:hover .drop-down-menu{
 display: block;
 height: 198px;
 opacity: 1;
 top: 40px;

 -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out; 
} /*This one is another that is not working*/

.content {
 z-index: -1;
 position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

   <nav class="nav-main">
    <div class="logo">
     <a href=""><img src="file:///Users/waynarbocangel/Documents/momoka_webpage/media/Logo-momoka--cono-l%C3%ADneas.png" alt="Momoka: Crepes & Arabica" class="logo" /></a>
    </div>
    
    <ul>
     <li class="nav-li"><a href="" class="nav-item">Home</a></li>
     <li class="nav-li"><a href="" class="nav-item">Menu</a>
        <ul class="drop-down-menu">
         <li><a href="">Coffees</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Crepes</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Juices and Teas</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-li"><a href="" class="nav-item">Offerts</a>
        <ul class="drop-down-menu">
         <li><a href="">Something</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Something</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Something</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-li"><a href="" class="nav-item">Contact</a>
        <ul class="drop-down-menu">
         <li><a href="">Something</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Something</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Something</a></li>
        </ul> 
     </li>
    </ul>
   
   </nav>

   <div class="content">
    <h1>Hi Welcome!</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vero albucius singulis mea ut. Qui tibique mentitum ea, pro dicta euripidis te. Ut mel sale antiopam. Est nobis homero cu, pro in cetero fabellas</p>

    <p>In vix epicurei pericula conclusionemque, vim abhorreant theophrastus conclusionemque ne. An ius option alterum tibique, iisque moderatius quo ne. Mei id utamur consequat sadipscing. Augue iudicabit expetendis mei ne. Iuvaret splendide ea mel, sumo clita vitae sit cu. In feugait expetenda nec. Quod sonet lobortis ius ne.</p>

    <p>Nec no veri verear, ex illum epicurei eam, dicat velit appetere no mea. Nulla persequeris comprehensam sit cu, eam inani nemore detracto ea. Vel ne graeci senserit, rebum erant nec ex, cum alii semper euripidis in. Semper utroque sapientem ex quo. Per id case interesset, percipit volutpat cum ex, in sit civibus instructior.</p>

    <p>Eos animal alterum cu, esse audire debitis ne his. Eos graeci indoctum efficiantur cu, est id tantas regione omnesque. Tota contentiones ut vel, mel idque sonet mnesarchum et. Vis eu forensibus referrentur, odio fierent te cum, qui mazim putent antiopam ex.
    </p>
   </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Could you trim this down to a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve please?

Answer (score 2):

Your transition is not working because you're changing the state from `display: none;` to `display: block`. A transition doesn't affect that. Leave the `display: block;` property on the second level `ul` and just have the height toggle between 0 and 198px when hovering. So like this:

```
.drop-down-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I owe you big time.

Comment: Not a problem. Be sure to test it in all browsers needed for your project to make sure it works correctly everywhere.